# python set seems to hold two identical objects

Tags: python, hash, set

I have two sets with custom objects in them.  I take the objects from one set and add them to the other set with set.update.

Afterwards, it appears that one set contains two identical objects:  their hash is identical, they are == to each other and not != to each other.  If I cast the set to a list and back to a set, I only have one object in the new set.  I have no other threads or processes running which may mutate the state of any object somehow in the middle.

I could post my **hash** and **eq** but they call multiple other sub-objects **hash** and **eq** and it would be a lot of code to include.

Instead here is the debugging code I am running and its output:

```
print('old hash', map(hash, node.incoming_edges))
print('new hash', map(hash, new_node.incoming_edges))
if len(new_node.incoming_edges) > 1:
    node1, node2 = list(new_node.incoming_edges)
    print('eq', node1 == node2)
    print('ne', node1 != node2)
print('type', type(node.incoming_edges))
print('type', type(new_node.incoming_edges))

new_node.incoming_edges.update(node.incoming_edges)

print('combined')
if len(new_node.incoming_edges) > 1:
    node1, node2 = list(new_node.incoming_edges)
    print('eq', node1 == node2)
    print('ne', node1 != node2)

print('combined hash', map(hash, new_node.incoming_edges))
print('len', len(new_node.incoming_edges))

new_node.incoming_edges = set(list(new_node.incoming_edges))

print('len', len(new_node.incoming_edges))
```

and the relevant output:

```
old hash [5805087492197093178]
new hash [5805087492197093178]
type <type 'set'>
type <type 'set'>
combined
eq True
ne False
combined hash [5805087492197093178, 5805087492197093178]
len 2
len 1
```

I was thinking that since my objects are recursive graphs, the hash might be changing by adding them to the sets, however I'm printing the hash before and after the operation to confirm that the hash is not changing.

How can this possibly be happening?  I would be happy to introduce more debug output, I can reproduce easily.

P.S.  Here is some info from pdb while I was trying to understand what is happening:

```
 57                     print('type', type(new_node.incoming_edges))
 58     
 59                     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
 60     
 61                     new_node.incoming_edges.update(node.incoming_edges)
 62  ->                 new_node.outgoing_edges.update(node.outgoing_edges)
 63                     # new_node.incoming_edges = set(list(new_node.incoming_edges))
 64     
 65                     print('combined')
 66                     if len(new_node.incoming_edges) > 1:
 67                         node1, node2 = list(new_node.incoming_edges)
(Pdb) !len(new_node.incoming_edges)
2
(Pdb) !x, y = new_node.incoming_edges
(Pdb) x
<Edge user.id getters={<SQLQuery tables:users; selects:users.last_name; where:{} input_mapping:{'id': 'users.id'}, <SQLQuery tables:users; selects:users.first_name; where:{} input_mapping:{'id': 'users.id'}} setter=None out=False>
(Pdb) y
<Edge user.id getters={<SQLQuery tables:users; selects:users.last_name; where:{} input_mapping:{'id': 'users.id'}, <SQLQuery tables:users; selects:users.first_name; where:{} input_mapping:{'id': 'users.id'}} setter=None out=False>
(Pdb) hash(x)
-8545778292158950550
(Pdb) hash(y)
-8545778292158950550
(Pdb) x == y
True
(Pdb) x != y
False
(Pdb) len(set(list(new_node.incoming_edges)))
1
(Pdb) len(new_node.incoming_edges)
2
```

Comment: You say posting your `__hash__` and `__eq__` would be a lot, since they end up checking a lot of subobjects. What kinds of subobject checks are involved? In particular, do you do any `==` comparisons on mutable objects, such as the edge endpoints?

Comment: Something's off here with your example.  Is this python 3?  Can't be, your `print`s would be printing `map` objects, not lists.  Is this python 2?  Can't be, your `print`s would be printing tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychic debugging: You've got `set` members in `node` that were added before this code begins, then mutated in a way that alters their hashes. `set` caches the hash value of each object on insertion and does not rehash under normal conditions; in fact, copying or updating from `set` to `set` can avoid rehashing as well, because it can copy the cached hash value directly instead of rehashing.

You "fixed" the problem when you convert to `list` (which effectively strips the cached hash values), then back to `set` (which must now rehash all the elements, which causes it to fix the duplication).

Of course, that's not a real fix. The real fix is to *NEVER* make mutable items hashable; follow Python's lead and either use immutable types only, or allow conversion from mutable to immutable variants, where only the immutable variants define `__hash__`. If you define `__hash__`, you're signing up for the rules for hashable types, which include logical immutability (and immutability for all attributes which are involved in the hash calculation too).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  That sounds about right.  I knew sets should always only include immutable objects, but for some reason didn't connect the dots that it would be the cause of this bug.  I'll go through and only put `__hash__` on immutable objects.  Thanks